# Nginx proxy_pass config leaves insecure access to location path open

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

The nginx snippet below works for https access of our web application. However several end users of the app are instead using ip access in browser to the same app with no certificate protection.
Ways to block this access?

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ourserver.com;
  return 301 https://ourserver.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen  443;
  server_name ourserver.com;
 
  ### SSL details removed
  ssl_certificate "//";
  ssl_certificate_key "//";
  ssl_session_cache
  ssl_session_timeout
  ssl_ciphers
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_read_timeout 1200;
    proxy_send_timeout 1200;
    proxy_connect_timeout 75;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have separate nginx server {} block virtual host which handles all requests to your server IP address? It might be in default nginx configuration.

Comment: Nope. I did see a block that can be used as an example in the default nginx config, `server {
        listen       8000;
        listen       somename:8080;
        server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }` I could put a redirection in there.

Comment: I mean, there is definately something in your config files which is responsible for handling all requests going to your IP address.